# Error complie code in excel vba

Tags: vba

When i compile code in vba, it show message Compiler to large.

my code over 30 line as the following:

```
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(dt, sheet2.Range("B11:E15"), 4, False)
sheet1.Range("E9").Value = result
```

Any solutions ?

Regards

Comment: Yes i run it on low pc hardware. it has many line of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751263/procedure-too-large

Comment: Please give the exact error message in its entirety. I doubt Microsoft misspelled their error message; usually it's "Procedure too large" Are you compiling on 32 bit or 64 bit computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this website http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983044 You need to break your code into smaller pieces to not exceed 64K. Also you need to write your code on 32 bit computer to guarantee compatibility.