# Procedure too large VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help to shorten this piece of code.

I need to use this code  `If (linha >= 20 And linha <= 21)` for 50 line (linha) intervals

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim foto As Range
  Dim destino As Range
  Dim linha As Long
  Dim fName As String
  Dim pName As String
  Dim iName As String
  Dim iNameClean As String
  Dim iNameExcel As String
  Dim fNameExcel As String

    Set foto = Target.Cells(1)
    Set destino = Me.Range("AU:BC,BN:BV,CG:CO,CZ:DH,DS:EA,EL:ET,FE:FM,FX:GF,GQ:GY,HJ:HR,IC:IK,IV:JD,JO:JW,KH:KP,NF:NN,NY:OG,OR:OZ,PK:PS")
    If Not Application.Intersect(foto, destino) Is Nothing Then
        linha = foto.Row


    If (linha >= 20 And linha <= 21) Then
        With ActiveSheet
    fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Picture files (*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.tif), *.jpgs;*.gif;*.bmp;*.tif", , _
"Select picture to insert")
            iName = Dir("" & fName & "")
            If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub
            iNameClean = Left(iName, Len(iName) - 4)
            iNameExcel = "+Info"
            fNameExcel = "F:\path\EXCEL\" & foto.Offset(1, 3).Value & ".xlsx"
            With ActiveSheet
            .Unprotect Password:="1234"
                ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fName).Select
                foto.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & fName & """,""" & iNameClean & """)"
                foto.Offset(0, 2).Font.ColorIndex = 1 ' preto
                foto.Offset(0, 2).Font.Size = 9
                foto.Offset(0, 2).Font.Underline = False
                foto.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & fNameExcel & """,""" & iNameExcel & """)"
                foto.Offset(0, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 1 ' preto
                foto.Offset(0, 3).Font.Size = 9
                foto.Offset(0, 3).Font.Underline = False
                With Selection.ShapeRange
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                    .Height = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Height
                    .Width = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Width
                    .Top = ActiveCell.Top
                    .Left = ActiveCell.Left
                End With
             .Protect Password:="1234"
            End With
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you can [edit] the title to succinctly explain *what the code does*, and expand a bit about the surrounding context in the question body, this would be a perfect question for [codereview.se]. As it stands, it's a bit *too broad* of a question to be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why do you need to shorten your code? If you get the error "procedure too large" then just break it down into several procedures. And if the module size is exceeded then distribute your code across several modules.

Comment: @Ralph If you get the "procedure too large" error, you have much bigger problems, and need to read up a bit on [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) ;-)

Comment: What do you mean "for 50 line (linha) intervals"?  I'm guessing this could be accomplished with a loop...

Comment: I'm getting the error because there is a bunch of lines of code. Just don't put them all here. I think you got it by reading what I wrote.

Comment: No, from the comments (mine, and others), the problem is that we **don't** understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I don't see how that as applicable to VBA. For all I can tell (and understand from the OP) the above question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751263/procedure-too-large

Comment: Ralph, You mean by call function, right?
I've tried but without success. 


Something like

End With
        End With

Call sublines

    End If
    
Sub sublines()
    If (linha >= 20 And linha <= 21) Then
(...)

Comment: @Ralph it's very likely applicable here. Assuming the contents of the `If` block can be compartmentalized to another sub/function(s) which accept some arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Ralph I will take a look

Comment: Oh wait, is that `If linha >= x And linha <= y Then` chunk copy+pasted so many times the procedure length actually goes beyond the limit? If so, then yeah @Ralph's link has your answer, and your question is a bit unclear. That said, if you're looking for help breaking it down into more manageable pieces and making it more efficient altogether, [codereview.se] remains the place to go.

Comment: Yes Mat'sMug  it's exactly that. I did not know that site. Thanks! I will try the Ralph's link first.

Comment: I can hardly imagine this small piece of code being too large. I have written far larger procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't put entire functional procedures in an event handler. Put only the minimal code required to route the event to the appropriate procedure. This keeps your event handlers concise, and easier to maintain. The bulk of the work will be happening in additional procedures.

I'll define a new procedure `DoStuff` which will process the `linha`s, and the parameters which we send to `DoStuff` can be controlled within a `Case` switch.

This way, the `DoStuff` procedure body doesn't need to be copied 50 times or more, you can simply add to the `Case` statements in the `Worksheet_Change` event handler, and making changes (if needed) on the optional parameters.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim foto as Range
  Dim destino as Range
  Dim linha As Long

    Set foto = Target.Cells(1)
    Set destino = Me.Range("AU:BC,BN:BV,CG:CO,CZ:DH,DS:EA,EL:ET,FE:FM,FX:GF,GQ:GY,HJ:HR,IC:IK,IV:JD,JO:JW,KH:KP,NF:NN,NY:OG,OR:OZ,PK:PS")
    If Not Application.Intersect(foto, destino) Is Nothing Then
        linha = foto.Row
    End If

    Select Case linha
        Case 20, 21
            Call DoStuff(foto, 1, 9, "1234")

        '### Simply add additional "Case" statements for each linha pair
        '    NOTE: You can send different parameters to the DoStuff procedure!
        Case 22, 23
            Call DoStuff(foto, 1, 9, "ABCD", "G:\another path\Excel\", ".xlsb")


        'Etc...

    End Select

End Sub
```

Here is the `DoStuff` procedure. This procedure takes the `foto` range (or, any range object, technically), and optional parameters (with default values) for `password`, `filepath`, `fileExt` (which are used in the `With` block).

```
Sub DoStuff(foto as Range, _
            Optional fontColor as Long=1, 
            Optional fontSize as Long=9, _
            Optional password as String="1234", _
            Optional filePath as String="F:\path\EXCEL\", _
            Optional fileExt as String=".xlsx")

  Dim fname as String
  Dim pName As String
  Dim iName As String
  Dim iNameClean As String
  Dim iNameExcel As String
  Dim fNameExcel As String

    If Right(filePath,1) <> "\" Then filePath = filePath & "\"

    fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Picture files (*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.tif), *.jpgs;*.gif;*.bmp;*.tif", , _
    "Select picture to insert")
    iName = Dir("" & fName & "")
    If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    iNameClean = Left(iName, Len(iName) - 4)
    iNameExcel = "+Info"
    fNameExcel = filePath & foto.Offset(1, 3).Value & fileExt

    With foto.Parent 'Worksheet
        .Unprotect Password:=password
        .Pictures.Insert(fName).Select
        With foto.Offset(0,2)
            .Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & fName & """,""" & iNameClean & """)"
            .Font.ColorIndex = fontColor ' preto
            .Font.Size = fontSize
            .Font.Underline = False
        End With
        With foto.Offset(0, 3)
            .Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & fNameExcel & """,""" & iNameExcel & """)"
            .Font.ColorIndex = fontColor ' preto
            .Font.Size = fontSize
            .Font.Underline = False
        End With
        With Selection.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Height = foto.MergeArea.Height
            .Width = foto.MergeArea.Width
            .Top = foto.Top
            .Left = foto.Left
        End With
     .Protect Password:=password
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Good advice. Seeing 200 lines of code in a single event handler is a pet peeve of mine. An event should always call a verb (method) with only arguments that might change as the program runs.

Comment: David Zemens You are the man! Thanks a lot!